CDC in PieCloudDB
I’m looking to implement Change Data Capture(CDC) so I can synchronize other systems with the changes. I learned that PostgreSQL can use Debezium for CDC. Can PieCloudDB also support Debezium? Or does it have other tools to implement CDC?

PieCloudDB has developed a tool DataFlow that supports extracting data from different databases and loading it into the target database. It currently implements CDC incremental synchronization of single tables and the entire database.
